# Need help to understand code in python

Tags: python

```
first = int(input('first int: '))
second = int (input('second int: '))
result =0
if first and second:
result =1
elif not first:
    result =2
elif first or second:
    result=3
else:
    result=4
print(result)
```

when I enter 1 and 0, the result is 3. I would appreciate if anyone could add some explanation.

Comment: No that's not a possible duplicate. Can't be!

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your latest question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `or`- it means the statement will return `True` when it first finds `True`.
When you say `5 or 9`, both 5 and 9 represent truism (as does any non-zero value). So it returns the first - 5 in this case. When you say `9 or 5`, it returns 9.

**EDIT**: `k = 1 or 0` would evaluate to `True` since 1 represents truism. Thus, as per your code, `result` is 3

Comment: "both 5 and 9 are vacuously `True`" - this is a very misleading description of what Python considers "true".

Comment: agreed...edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In many program languages, the boolean operations only evaluate their second argument if needed for their outcome. These called short-circuit operator. And in python, according the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), it returns:

```
x or y  :   if x is false, then y, else x
x and y :   if x is false, then x, else y
```